# How to swap the X and Y axis of a graph in Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

Transposing the table does not help. Every time I get this graph:

[image]

I tried to swap the axes in the Select Data Source dialogue but then I get this:

[image]

Now the letters (they are departments in real world, I just simplified it) are on the vertical axis, but the horizontal axis is wrong. Of course the graph is also wrong as I don't need two vertical axes. I need the columns to be horizontal as that graph would be much easier to read.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose another type of graph. Try the 'bar'-type. (You can change it by right-click -> Change type).